# Does the VDGS have a sign for stopping too early?

Tags: ground-operations

I got a report from one our personnel who was watching the aircraft going in the stand under the Visual Docking Guidance System (VDGS). The aircraft was forwarding with extreme cautions and the captain kept her eye on the display that was showing distance remaining. At about the 1.5m display, the aircraft stayed on the spot for a second then VDGS display popped up the sign “STOP” despite the aircraft not having reaching the desired spot on the stand markings.

I complained about this situation to the VDGS operation team just showing "STOP" even though the aircraft was stopped too early. They said there is no problem about the situation, all things were in accordance with the procedure.

Is there really no problem about the way the operation team popped the STOP sign up even the aircraft was parked before the marking?

Does the VDGS system not have a separate sign for stopping too early? I searched on the internet and it seems like there is “TOO FAR” or “T-FAR” sign for stopping too late, but I cannot see another sign for too early.

Comment: I thought these systems are fully automated? There should be no-one operating them as such, there certainly is no "team" operating an individual VDGS. Plane type is somehow entered into VDGS, but then it should operate on its own.

Comment: It could be, @Jpe61, that the employee was visually monitoring as part of a testing/calibration, not monitoring as in "operating the system". Otherwise, fully agree with your question.

Comment: perhaps 1.5m is close enough? these systems are used with airliners, right? that are 30m long or so, or longer?

Comment: @user253751 Yes, they are used by airliners, but they usually have to park quite precisely. See here: [Why do airliners have to park so accurately?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/54317/why-do-airliners-have-to-park-so-accurately)